# How to convert diffrent time format in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Microsoft Excel, what is the proper format  to convert the following time format

```
39:25.0 (Display in the cell)

19/5/2017  8:39:25 AM (Display in the Formula Bar)
```

into the following format

```
2017-05-19 08:39:25.019544
```

The file is originally save as `csv`, but upon opening it using Microsoft Excel, it seem the time format was changed.

The csv content is

```
onset,duration,description
2017-05-19 08:39:25.019544,14.169381107491855,some_info
```

Or, downloadable via the following [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e-Ce_bWskUBGlpZo_IHqMRYHId2tOszm/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: 1.  Excel only goes to the 1000th of a second.  2. What is `,14.169381107491855`?

Comment: if it is a csv, then the `14.169381107491855` would go into another cell.  To format the time.  format the cell: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.000` or format the cells as text before importing the data, or use the import wizard and make the cells text on the import.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply @ScottCraner, as per my edit, the file is originally saved as `csv` from the mne annotation package. However, opening it using MS Excel changed mess the formating.

Comment: Add the first couple of lines from your CSV to the question using [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63287507/edit)

Comment: The answer from @ScottCraner is correct, use format as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.000`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @scott,, The answer is correct, but the `019544` has been rounded to `020`. Since our application is in range of `1000Hz`, this distort the signal considerably. Any ways to tackle this issue? Also, you can make your suggestion as an answer for me to accept it.